# Does the series converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of positive reals satisfying 
$$ a_n\le a_{2n}+a_{2n+1} $$

What can we say about the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n $ ?

Comment: Nothing. $a_n = 0$ converges and satisfies the inequality, $a_n=1$ diverges and satisfies the inequality.

Comment: Its about **positive** real numbers. That means $> 0 $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summing the inequality from $n=1$ to $m$ we obtain

$$\sum_{n=1}^m a_n\le \sum_{n=2}^{2m+1} a_n$$

Subtracting $\sum_{n=2}^m a_n$ from either side, we get

$$\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty a_n>\sum_{n=m+1}^{2m+1} a_n\ge a_1>0$$

This implies divergence, because if the series would converge, then $\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty a_n$ would have to converge to $0$ as $m\rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

If $s_n$ is the $n$th partial sum show that $s_n$ is not Cauchy. To do so have a look at $s_{2^{m+1}-1}-s_{2^{m}-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: think about $a_1, a_2+a_3, a_4+a_5+a_6+a_7, \dots, \sum_{i=2^k}^{2^{k+1}-1}a_i,\dots$

Answer (score 0):

> If $a_n\gt0$ for at least one index $n$ then the series diverges.

To show this, assume that $a_k\gt0$ and, for every $n\geqslant0$, consider 
$$A_n=\sum_{i=2^nk}^{2^n(k+1)-1}a_i.
$$
Then $A_0=a_k$ and, for every $n\geqslant0$, $A_{n+1}\geqslant A_n$. In particular, $A_n\geqslant a_k\gt0$ hence the rest of the series $\sum\limits_ia_i$ does not converge to $0$.