# Does this sequence of real numbers converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of strictly positive real numbers s.t. 
$a_n≤a_{2n}+a_{2n+1}$. Does the sum over $a_n$ converge or diverge?

I've played around with the inequality and believe that the sum diverges, but can't seem to find a rigorous proof. I used the counter example $a_n=n$ to show it doesn't converge.

Comment: I am pretty sure your counter example is right, you are looking for a proof that this series doesn't convergence?

Comment: Does that problem have another condition? I mean the inequality without any other restriction is pretty weak.

Comment: @YTS: The only other condition needed is that $a_1>0$.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/682705/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1159430/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1049433/42969.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conjecture is correct. HINT: Show by induction on $n$ that $a_1\le\sum_{k=2^n}^{2^{n+1}-1}a_k$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$.